# EasyTabs and KnockoutJS Conflict

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the EasyTabs plugin (http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs) together with KnockoutJS. I have a panel that must not be showed when there is no item available. So I put the following code:

```
<div data-bind="if: machine() !== null">
```

This div contains the tab container. When a machine is available. The panel is visible. But the tabs do not work. You can click on it, the browser's address bar shows the name of the clicked tag, but the tab window does not change.

When I erase the data-bind in the div. It works, but off course, the panel is visible, and that is not what I want.

Known problem or is there any work-around available?

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/jurgenstillaert/fdt8d/

Comment: Can you post some more code how is your tabs sturcuted? Maybe a working repro in JSFiddle...

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle example.

Comment: You need a custom bindinghandler as ebohlman described in his answer. So you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NbYa9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your jsFiddle, I fixed it like this:

```
<div id="cntrMyTabs" class="tab-container" data-bind="visible: isShow">
   <ul class='etabs'>
      <li class='tab'><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class='tab'><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tab1" class="panel-container">
       This is tab 1.
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="panel-container">
       This is tab 2.
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice outer div is gone and visible data-bind is added. Reason why this works and yours doesn't is because in yours the inner html is not part of the DOM and as others have stated, it doesn't become easytabs when you checkbox it. With this, this is part of the DOM, just hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that EasyTabs won't do anything with the tabs unless `easytabs()` has been called on the container element. Since that element doesn't actually become part of the DOM until your `if` binding succeeds, and then disappears from the DOM when it fails, that initialization never happens.

You'll need to write a custom binding that calls `easytabs()` on the appropriate container element in its `update` method.